# Switch off DEP from command line in Win 2003

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2003, dep

How can I switch off DEP from command line in Win 2003?

Or at least for Win XP.

A lot of forums explain how switch it off by editing boot.ini, but I need command line solution.

Comment: Alex: this is way off topic and it might occur to you that since (a) everybody mentions boot.ini (b) this is a _core kernel_ facility you might simply need to do what you're finding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 you might want to use `BOOTCFG` to disable DEP, see [/noexecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

> bootcfg /raw "/noexecute=alwaysoff"

Comment: It asks for ID parameter. And I need to pass ID of current running system. It will be sad to switch off DEP for neighbour system and not to switch off for current.

Comment: maybe you know how to figure out id?

Comment: Identifiers are 1, 2 etc, the whole configuration can be queried via `bootcfg /query`, but I don't think you can do everything in batch file (if you need it), as the data is formatted for interactive user.

Answer (score 0):

It's not commandline, but perhaps you can use

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>, **A**dvanced, **P**erformance Options, `Data Execution Prevention` tab

where you can even manage DEP settings per application

Answer (score 0):

run cmd as an admin and enter below in

bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff

Comment: Can you explain what this does? That way it's easier for the OP to understand what you're suggesting.