# Web Applications and Disabling DEP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, atl, dep

I have some old web applications written years ago that seem to be incompatible with DEP. I tell people offsite to disable DEP for these applications and the response is "But these are web apps!".

This confuses me. Can one disable DEP for web apps? Is there even a difference? Can someone explain and illuminate the process required to disable DEP for specific web apps?

Thanks,

Comment: By DEP do you mean - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable DEP for specific processes by putting them onto exception list: My Computer, Properties, Advanced, Performance, Settings, DEP. See http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_turn_off_data_execution_prevention_errors.html

You might be also interested in these:

- [IIS: How to disable Data Execution Prevention in Windows Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209052/iis-how-to-disable-data-execution-prevention-in-windows-server-2008)
- [Switch off DEP from command line in Win 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661178/switch-off-dep-from-command-line-in-win-2003)